# Dotnet: Where does the tool directory get added to PATH?

Tags: .net, zsh

Looking at PATH with dotnet installed yields `[...]:/home/x150/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/x150/.dotnet/tools`. My .zshrc or .zshenv have no additional `export PATH="$PATH:/home/x150/.dotnet/tools"` though, so I wonder where dotnet adds `/home/x150/.dotnet/tools` to path.

Comment: There are more files in involved in starting up a zsh than the two you mentioned. I would create a new zsh **login**-shell with `-x` turned on, and analyze the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: Shell script that adds `.dotnet/tools` is in `/etc/profile.d/dotnet-cli-tools-bin-path.sh`